# integrating css styles to my email sent for contact form email

Tags: php, html, css, forms, email

How do I use css to style the email that will be sent from my contact form ?
I have tried adding css inline styles to the code but it just breaks it.
I would just like to add a message and style the font and add an image/ logo.

---

```
<?php

include 'config.php';

error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

if($post)
{

<html>
<h1>This is a test email<h1>

$name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$subject = stripslashes($_POST['subject']);
$message = stripslashes($_POST['message']);

$error = '';

</html>


if(!$error)
{
$mail = mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, $subject, $message,
     "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n"
    ."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"
    ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());


if($mail)
{
echo 'OK';
}

}


}
?>
```

---

I would like to add this to the first bit of code so it styles the email that is sent from the contact form.

```
              <span STYLE=\"font-size:20px; color: #333333\"><p>You have recieved a new message enquiry from <a href=\"http://www.google.co.uk\">www.test.co.uk</a> contact form.</p></span>
              <p>
              <p>
              <div STYLE=\"font-size:16px\">
              <p><strong>Name:</strong> {$name} </p>
              <p><strong>Email Address:</strong> {$email}</strong> </p>
              <p><strong>subject:</strong> {$subject} </p>
              <p><strong>Message:</strong> {$message} </p>

              <h3><p></p></h3>

              <div>
              <dr />
              <span STYLE=\"font-style:italic;font-size:large; color: #333333\">This message was sent from the IP Address: {$ipaddress} on {$date} at {$time}</span></div> 

             </body>
            </html>"
```

Comment: why -1 do you need more info ?

Comment: You realize that you're injecting raw HTML into PHP.

Comment: Im new to php so no im not to sure what im doing

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
<?php

include 'config.php';
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

if($post) {
    echo '
    <html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <h1>This is a test email<h1>
    ';

    $name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $subject = stripslashes($_POST['subject']);
    $message = stripslashes($_POST['message']);

    $error = '';

    if(!$error) {
        $mail = mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, $subject, $message,
             "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n"
            ."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"
            ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
        if($mail) {
            echo 'OK';
        }
    }
    echo '</html>';
}

?>
```

You have to set your styles, for example, on that css file.

Once you have opened php code (`<?php ?>`), if you want to include html code you have two options. You can write that code with the echo function (with `""` or `''` before and after the html code): `<?php PHP_CODE echo 'HTML_CODE'; MORE_PHP_CODE ?>` or `<?php PHP_CODE echo "HTML_CODE"; MORE_PHP_CODE ?>`. You can also close the php section and reopen it later: `<?php PHP_CODE ?> HTML_CODE <?php MORE_PHP_CODE ?>`.

You have to take care about the html code you want the echo function to write. If you open echo with `'`, you can't put html code inside with that symbol because you will close the echo sentence. The same happens using echo with `"` character. You can't write html code with `"` inside.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like the h1 to show up in the email its self how would I do this?

Comment: With the mail function: `mail($recipient,$subject,$body,$headers)` you have to include all the html code of the email in the third argument ($body).

Comment: would you please give me an example ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you close your `<?php` tag before outputting HTML content, or use `echo` statements if you'd rather write the HTML from within the `<?php` tag.  Once you do that, I suspect it'll be easier to apply your CSS without issues.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140270/how-to-write-html-code-inside-php) for more information.