# How to add a id tag in php output?

Tags: php, css, html

I have to add an html id tag to give some css properties inside this php code and I don't know how to do that?

```
   <?php

   //Start your session
   session_start();
   //Read your session (if it is set)
   if (isset($_SESSION['user_login'])){

 echo $_SESSION['user_login'];
         }
?>
```

I have to add css property for that echo.

Comment: what is you expected O/p?

Comment: Can you explain more what's your actual requirement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write html code inside <?php ?>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140270/how-to-write-html-code-inside-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you want something like this -

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_login']))
{ 
echo '<div id="YOUR-ID-HERE">'.$_SESSION['user_login'].'</div>';
}
```

Comment: Thx man Working! I can't upvote this answer bacause of low reputation.

Comment: Its okay, no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

This is simple HTML 101,

```
<tagname id="idValue">
```

Have you tried looking though [w3schools](http://w3schools.com/html/default.asp)

Comment: What areyou trying to do? Can you edit your question so we can see what you are doing? What error do you get etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose (wrap) your PHP output in a `div`.

And then give `id` to that div.

```
<div id="YOUR_CSS_ID_HERE">
<?php echo $_SESSION['user_login'];?>
</div>
```

Also, no need for brackets `(` and `)` for `echo` as it is a language construct, not a function.