# Loading External js File in PHP Class

Tags: javascript, php

In a php class, assuming the js file is in the same directory, but I can never predict where the two files will be located on the server, how do I make sure the js file is properly referenced?

This doesn't work at all:

```
    function import_script() {
    ?>
        <script src="<?php echo(__DIR__); ?>\myscriptfile.js"></script>
```

I hope this is clear enough - enough code foryou to see what I'm trying to do.  Feel free to request more and I'll edit the question.

Comment: You need to know locations of js file, dont do dir__, give path /pathtojs/jsfile.js relative to web document root

Comment: please elaborate more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can even try this

```
function import_script() {
    echo "<script src='".__DIR__."/myscriptfile.js'></script>";
}
```

For more reference check this SO question [how to write HTML inside PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140270/how-to-write-html-code-inside-php)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any of the fancy coding just put a `.` before the first slash like this:

```
<script src="./myscriptfile.js"></script>
```

When getting directory listings, you notice there is `.` and `..`, `.` indicates current directory, while `..` indicates the parent directory. All without having to know the current directories name, so you could change it every hour, the script would work then same.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple question with a vast answers. Keeping your assets in relative directory or absolute, might require some knowledge on your framework, but simply:

```
function import_script() {
?>
    <script src="myscriptfile.js"></script>
```

if you are pretty sure it's located same directory as your php url file.