# I want to split the html and php code ? it a little bit confusing to write this way

Tags: php, html

```
$message .= "<tr><th>First Name</th><td>".$_POST['fname']."</td><th>Last Name</th><td>".$_POST['lname']."</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><th>Email</th><td>".$_POST['email']."</td><th>Telephone number</th><td>".$_POST['telno']."</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><th>Company Name</th><td>".$_POST['cname']."</td><th>Mobile number</th><td>".$_POST['mobileno']."</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><th>Address</th><td>".$_POST['address']."</td><th>City</th><td>".$_POST['city']."</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><th>Zip Code</th><td>".$_POST['zipcode']."</td><th>State</th><td>".$_POST['state']."</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><th>Country</th><td>".$_POST['country']."</td><th>Fax</th><td>".($_POST['fax'] == '' ? 'NA' : $_POST['fax'])."</td></tr>";
$message .= "<table>";
```

- Just want to write HTML and PHP separately how to write?
- Please show in different way to write PHP and HTML file?
- I want to write  `$message` ie variable only once in the program?

Also show how to write this code HTML and PHP in same page of `file.php` but splitting HTML and PHP

Comment: You can just exit PHP-mode, `?>` and use HTML as you want - then where you need PHP variables, open a PHP tag, do what needs to be done - and you can then go out again. Example: `<?php /* some PHP */ ?><tr><th>....<?php echo $_POST['fname']; ?></td>` and so on.

Comment: please do it   for  first line First Name?

Comment: I sort of already did... ;-) The start of it, anyway. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18140338/4535200

Comment: Splitting PHP and raw HTML sections only makes sense for direct output. Not for assignment to a variable. What you rather want to investigate are HEREDOC strings to simplify that pile of code. (And context escaping, for that matter.)

Comment: $message .= "<tr><th>Plastic Coated Paper</th><td>".($_POST['plastic_coated_paper'] == 'Select Paper' ? 'NA' : $_POST['plastic_coated_paper']).
    "</td><th>100% Pure Plastic</th><td>".($_POST['pure_plastic'] == 'Select Plastic' ? 'NA' : $_POST['pure_plastic'])."</td></tr>";       i want to remove only dot from     .$_POST['']== ''  and write in different way .....any idea

Comment: double quotes in php process php variable too, so you dont need to concatenate $_POST with string, just write it within the string and it will work :)

`$message .= "<tr><th>First Name</th><td>$_POST['fname']</td><th>Last Name</th><td>$_POST['lname']</td></tr>";`

Comment: If you want to clean your code further use can use `sprintf()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: can i echo the $_POST or write it with <?php   echo $_POST['fname']?>

Answer (score 0):

double quotes in php process php variable too, so you dont need to concatenate $_POST with string, just write it within the string and it will work :)

```
$message .= "<tr><th>First Name</th><td>$_POST['fname']</td><th>Last Name</th><td>$_POST['lname']</td></tr>";
```

If you want to clean your code further use can use `sprintf()` [php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple HTML structure in your php file.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th> 
        <td> <?php $_POST['fname']; ?> </td>
        <th>Last Name</th> 
        <td> <?php $_POST['lname']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Email</th> 
        <td> <?php $_POST['email']; ?> </td>
        <th>Telephone number</th>
        <td> <?php $_POST['telno']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Company Name</th> 
        <td><?php $_POST['cname']; ?></td>
        <th>Mobile number</th>
        <td><?php $_POST['mobileno']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Address</th>
        <td><?php $_POST['address']; ?></td>
        <th>City</th>
        <td><?php $_POST['city']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Zip Code</th>
        <td><?php $_POST['zipcode']; ?></td>
        <th>State</th>
        <td><?php $_POST['state']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Country</th>
        <td><?php $_POST['country']; ?></td>
        <th>Fax</th>
        <td><?php ($_POST['fax'] == '' ? 'NA' : $_POST['fax']); ?</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you want to put all this code into a variable (f.ex. $message), as a variant, you can do the next.
Put all code  into one php file (f.ex. table.php) and in the other file (f.ex. index.php) include it by writing such code:

```
<?php
    $message = require_once __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'table.php';
    echo $message;
?>
```