# Export from MYSQL to HTML

Tags: html, windows

I am new to MYSQL and i am trying to export my database to html, and put the data into specific html tables. I have looked around the site, but i cant get my code to work, can someone help me, and tell me if this code looks right ?

```
<?php

    $con=mysqli_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM xxx");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        <tr>
            <th bgcolor="#3281c6">" . $row["PO_nummer"]. "</th>
            <th bgcolor="#3281c6">" . $row["Varenummer"]. "</th>
            <th bgcolor="#3281c6">" . $row["Produkt_beskrivelse_"]. "</th>
            <th bgcolor="#3281c6">" . $row["Antal"]. "</th>
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: what is the issue (exception/incorrect UI rendering etc), highlighting will not force people here to assume your problems.

Comment: duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902483/show-values-from-a-mysql-database-table-inside-a-html-table-in-a-page/17902527#17902527

Comment: It's a good start to write youre html and php with quotes, or outside <?php tags. Check on how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140270/how-to-write-html-code-inside-php

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be expecting an associative array and not a regular (numbered) array, in this case try:

`while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
{
// code
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try and echo or print the html

```
echo "
<th bgcolor="#3281c6">" . $row["PO_nummer"]. "             </th>
<th bgcolor="#3281c6">" . $row["Varenummer"]. "</th>
<th bgcolor="#3281c6">" . $row["Produkt_beskrivelse_"]. "</th>
<th bgcolor="#3281c6">" . $row["Antal"]. "</th>";
```

And use single quotes here `bgcolor='#3281c6'`