# HTML within PHP syntax

Tags: php, html, syntax

I'm trying to show a submit button based on a logical statement using PHP and HTML, but I can't figure out the syntax.

```
if(isset($_POST['newSubmit'])){ 
    <input type="submit" name="newSubmit" id="newSubmit" value="Select" />;    
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. Do I need to use an echo statement?

Comment: Use echo,
 echo '<input type="submit" name="newSubmit" id="newSubmit" value="Select" /> ';

Comment: Use this <?php .....     if(isset($_POST['newSubmit'])){  ?>  <input type="submit" name="newSubmit" id="newSubmit" value="Select" />; <?php } ?>

Comment: [More info about writing html with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140270/how-to-write-html-code-inside-php)

Answer (score 3):

You have to do echo in php or write input outside php

**1) echo to display**

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['newSubmit'])){ 
   echo '<input type="submit" name="newSubmit" id="newSubmit" value="Select" />';    
} ?>
```

**2)write html Out side php**

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['newSubmit'])){ ?>
    <input type="submit" name="newSubmit" id="newSubmit" value="Select" />
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I think you got the `php`'s opening and closing tag wrong

Comment: @Swellar Its not wrong I have updated only solution from question provided guessing that `php` tag starting at beginning and closed at end of file.Which doest not stated here. BTW I have aded tags

Answer (score 0):

When generating html in php you need to either use echo or enclose php tags

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['newSubmit'])){ 
    echo '<input type="submit" name="newSubmit" id="newSubmit" value="Select" />';    
}
?>
```

or

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['newSubmit'])){?> 
<input type="submit" name="newSubmit" id="newSubmit" value="Select" />    
<?php}?>
```