# Display PHP code

Tags: php, html

I have an array called **memberList** which is filled with a list of members.

Now I am trying to use PHP to loop through the array and display it on the page.

```
<tr class='d1'><td><p class='normal-text5'><?=$memberList[$x]?></p></td></tr>
```

I wanted to loop through it using a for loop, instead of having to copy/paste the same code 100 times, displaying every name.

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 99; $x++) {
echo <tr class='d1'><td><p class='normal-text5'><?=$memberList[$x]?></p></td></tr>
}
```

But then I remembered you can't execute PHP code in an Echo, so I was wondering how I could do this differently?

Comment: i am suggesting you to read about how to embed html in php.https://stackoverflow.com/a/18140338/1939258

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write html code inside <?php ?>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140270/how-to-write-html-code-inside-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in your code

```
echo <tr class='d1'><td><p class='normal-text5'><?=$memberList[$x]?></p></td></tr>
```

this should be

```
echo "<tr class='d1'><td><p class='normal-text5'>".$memberList[$x]."</p></td></tr>";
```

echo statements print out a string or variable. in case you have both, you need to use concatenate operator as well. You did not put any for the string (html string) quotes "" you wanted to print out nor you concatenated those strings.

this is the main reason you get nothing/error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  <?php 
    for ($x = 0; $x <= 99; $x++) {
      echo "<tr class='d1'><td><p class='normal-text5'>".$memberList[$x]."
         </p</td>
      </tr>"
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: this will print nothing, because if you want to place the code this way, you need to place opening and closing php tags before and after body of loop <?php and ?>

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using foreach to iterate over the array, for instance:

```
foreach ($memberList as $key=>$member) {
  echo "<tr class='d1'><td><p class='normal-text5'>".$member."</p></td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: php concatenation operator is .(dot) not +(plus).

Comment: he said he wanted to use for loop and not foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

please try using this

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i <= 99; $i++) { ?>  <!--for loop open-->
   <tr class='d1'>                       <!--HTML content-->
    <td>
        <p class='normal-text5'><?php echo $memberList[$i]?></p> <!--echo php variable/ perform any php operation -->
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>                              <!--for loop close-->
```