# Read data to website inside html tags from Google sheets using php

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-api, google-client

I have written some php code to read and write data to google sheets using google spreadsheets api but that code runs only in CLI. Is there any way to show those data on my website within html tags?

For example I want to show those data in `<p>` tag.

I've been searching for days but haven't found the way yet. Please help me out.

Comment: try to add API Consent in your website with `Client_id`

Comment: From your issue, as far as I understand,  you want to write data into html tag using php at your website. You could get help from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140270/how-to-write-html-code-inside-php

Comment: https://gist.github.com/pamelafox/770584/f1ae212019c3305edd90cdc20d2725da4f181a51, https://www.fillup.io/post/read-and-write-google-sheets-from-php/ could help you